# In Node JS, I have an async operation that does not resolve. How do I use worker thread to abort it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, worker-thread, node-worker-threads

Say I have an async operation like so:

```
    async () => {
       await longTask().then(result => console.log(result));
    }
```

Let's say longTask is unpredictable. It hangs and does not resolve some of the time.

I understand that we can't just abort an async operation.

I looked into **[worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_terminate)** so that I can spawn a worker to run this async operation and terminate it if need be.

Unfortunately when I tried it, the whole program exits.

Is there a way for me to **abort/terminate/cancel/kill** a worker thread and just remove the async operation, without exiting the node app?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you could have a look here https://dev.to/chromiumdev/cancellable-async-functions-in-javascript-5gp7. I think this sounds like what you need

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from the Node.js documentation on Cluster [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_disconnect), a possible approach can be the following:

Main.js

```js
const { fork } = require('child_process');
const WORKER_PATH = 'PATH_TO_WORKER_JS';
const INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 seconds
let CHECKS = 0; // keep count of how many times you check for completion

const worker = fork(WORKER_PATH);

// send message to start the async process

worker.send({ start: true }, err => {
   if(err) { // handle error }
});

// check for completion on the worker

setTimeout(() => {
    worker.send({ checkIsDone: true }, err => {});
}, INTERVAL);

// listen for message from worker

function checkMsg(msg) {
   const { done } = msg;
   if(done) {
       // async process ended; kill the worker
       worker.kill('SIGKILL');
   } else {
      if(check > 10) {
         // checked 10 times for completion, 10 seconds apart; 
         // process not terminating so force kill
         worker.send('SIGKILL');
      } else {
         // setup another check in 10 seconds
         setTimeout(() => {
             worker.send({ checkIsDone: true }, err => {});
         }, INTERVAL);
      }
      CHECKS++;
   }
}

process.on('message', checkMsg);
```

Worker.js

```js
let isDone = false;

async function indeterministicProcess() {

   // some long computation
   
   // finished
}

process.on('message', msg => {
    const { checkIsDone, start } = msg;
    if(start) { 
        // start your async process 
        interdeterministicProcess().then(() => (isDone = true)).catch(e => console.error(e));
    } else if(checkIsDone) {
       if(isDone) {
           // send done message to master
           process.send({ done: true}, err => {});
       } else {
          process.send({ done: false}, err => {});
       }

    }
});
```

This is an approach I have used a few times in the past and has worked for me really well. Hope this gives you some idea on how to implement this for your use case.